# Is it possible to make update the docker image after pushing it to dockerhub/ACR/etc at runtime as docker cp command works on localhost

Tags: docker

I have a angular application and I have created an docker image of that, I have published it on Azure Container Register(ACR).

I want to pull the image from ACR and deploy it to Azure App service, and change the images, css files from the docker container at runtime.

I want to know if it is possible to update the images/css file at runtime as we do using docker cp command on localhost.

Comment: You will be better off updating your Dockerfile to build the image as you need it.  Especially when you get into distributed cloud environments, workflows built around manual `docker cp` or `docker exec` tend to not work especially well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CI/CD for this purpose.
Just create a webhook in ACR. So, whenever the image gets updates, the WebApp will automatically get "notified" and pull in the new change.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your input, that probably resolved my issue